# Change selected item based on other selected item

Tags: jquery

This should be really simple but nothing is working yet. I have 2 select list, 'UsersList' and 'RolesList', each with an empty option tag at the beginning ( Html.DropDownList). When someone selects an option from the first, I want the other's "selected" option to clear, or go to the first item (with no value), and vice-versa. Seems simple enuff. Thanks in advance.

The jquery:

```
       $("#UsersList").on('change', function (event) {
        $('#RolesList').selectedIndex = 1;            
        });
```

The generated HTML:

```
<select id="UsersList" name="UsersList"><option value=""></option>
 <option value="14ab6df2f585hhhh47fd">user1</option>
 <option value="73d50cce-02e45f76cfb">user2</option>
 <option value="9fddda3-b7a9-dd188b7">user2</option>
 <option value="0b56fe3d-t06566b897b">user4</option>
</select>

<select id="RolesList" name="RolesList"><option value=""></option>
 <option value="admin">admin</option>
 <option value="df">user</option>
 <option value="docadmin">Documen tAdmin</option> 
 <option value="UserAdmin">UserAdmin</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#UsersList").on('change', function (event) {
    $('#RolesList').val('');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EPWLY/)**

Comment: for some reason this only worked for me when I changed it slightly: "$('#UsersList').change(function ()". Firefox's Venkman JS debugger kept telling me "(...).on" wasnt a valid event(???). Im not sure if the other ways work also, but since I'll be checking the value of the inputs later this seemed the most accurate. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#RolesList').prop('selectedIndex',1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FJ8YP/1/

Answer (score 0):

This way also works `get()` grabs the dom element associated with the jquery object:

```
$("#UsersList").on('change', function (event) {
    $('#RolesList').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;            
});
```